# System.StringException: Invalid id: a5bK0000000HSWA

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

I am trying to get the id of the record from email subject.

This is the subject of my email and ID  `a5bK0000000HSWA`

Subject: `ABSI for approval. ref: a5bK0000000HSWA`

Now I am getting the id using apex

```
Id recordId = subject.substring((subject.indexOf('ref:')) + 4, subject.length());
String dealPrefix = Early_Termination__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
if (String.valueOf(recordId).startsWith(dealPrefix)) {
}
```

But I am getting the error

> System.StringException: Invalid id: a5bK0000000HSWA

Could anyone please help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you have leading space in concrete Id value. You can check it by means of changing `recordId` type to string:

```
String subject = 'ABSI for approval. ref: a5bK0000000HSWA';
String recordId = subject.substring((subject.indexOf('ref:')) + 4, subject.length());
System.debug(recordId);
```

> DEBUG|**space goes here**a5bK0000000HSWA

---

`subject.indexOf('ref:')` returns index of `r` symbol. to start getting concrete id, you need to skip 5 more symbols, because length of `ref:` is 5 symbols including space.

so change **4** to **5**

```
Id recordId = subject.substring((subject.indexOf('ref:')) + 5, subject.length());
String dealPrefix = Early_Termination__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
if (String.valueOf(recordId).startsWith(dealPrefix)) {
}
```